# Criar botão flutuante que acompanhe o scroll de um table

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Preciso criar um botão flutuante que acompanhe meu *scroll* conforme vou rolando, e nele quero colocar uma função voltar ao topo.

```
#voltarAoTopo {
  float:right;
  z-index:0;
}

<button id="voltarAoTopo">
    <i class="material-icons">contacts</i>
</button>
```

[image: Tabela]

Comment: Só colocar `position: fixed`

Comment: mas como faço para colocar embaixo do meu body, está aparecendo a imagem que coloquei pra você ?

Comment: Fala Nicola! Blz? Cara, dá uma finalizada nesta pergunta marcando ✔ numa resposta. Não precisa ser a minha, mas a que vc achou melhor, pra pergunta não ficar em aberta. Abs!

Answer (score 2):

É só criar um botão fixo no canto inferior direito, e colocar uma função em JavaScript para voltar ao topo. O botão só irá aparecer após 20 pixels de scroll (isso você pode ajustar como quiser):

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
}

function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
p{
display: block; height: 2500px;}

#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<p>Role para baixo</p>
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Ir ao topo">Topo</button>
```

### Bônus: Animação usando JS puro

Crédito do código **[neste link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26808520/1377664)**.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();

function scrollToY(scrollTargetY, speed, easing) {
    // scrollTargetY: the target scrollY property of the window
    // speed: time in pixels per second
    // easing: easing equation to use

    var scrollY = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
        scrollTargetY = scrollTargetY || 0,
        speed = speed || 2000,
        easing = easing || 'easeOutSine',
        currentTime = 0;

    // min time .1, max time .8 seconds
    var time = Math.max(.1, Math.min(Math.abs(scrollY - scrollTargetY) / speed, .8));

    // easing equations from https://github.com/danro/easing-js/blob/master/easing.js
    var easingEquations = {
            easeOutSine: function (pos) {
                return Math.sin(pos * (Math.PI / 2));
            },
            easeInOutSine: function (pos) {
                return (-0.5 * (Math.cos(Math.PI * pos) - 1));
            },
            easeInOutQuint: function (pos) {
                if ((pos /= 0.5) < 1) {
                    return 0.5 * Math.pow(pos, 5);
                }
                return 0.5 * (Math.pow((pos - 2), 5) + 2);
            }
        };

    // add animation loop
    function tick() {
        currentTime += 1 / 60;

        var p = currentTime / time;
        var t = easingEquations[easing](p);

        if (p < 1) {
            requestAnimFrame(tick);

            window.scrollTo(0, scrollY + ((scrollTargetY - scrollY) * t));
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, scrollTargetY);
        }
    }

    // call it once to get started
    tick();
}

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
p{
display: block; height: 2500px;}

#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<p>Role para baixo</p>
<button onclick="scrollToY(0, 10000, 'easeInOutSine');" id="myBtn" title="Ir ao topo">Topo</button>
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. Eu tentei fazer a mesma coisa. Cheguei nessa parte até achar a sua solução para o problema.

`/* const sectionCourses = document.querySelector(".section3");
const goTop = document.getElementById("gototop");


if (window.scrollY >= sectionCourses.offsetTop) {
  goTop.style.display = "block";
} else {
  goTop.style.display = "none";
} */`

Meu maior problema foi não ter usado uma function e utilizado isso aqui:
`window.onscroll = function(){
      scrollFunction()
  };`

Poderia me explicar essa parte?

Comment: `window.onscroll` detecta quando a janela sofre _scroll_ (rolagem) e dispara uma função. Você poderia escrever assim, mais simplificado: `window.onscroll = scrollFunction;`. Como `scrollFunction` já é uma função, não precisa colocá-la dentro de outra `function`.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Defina o z-index:
considerando 9 como acima tudo, e 0 abaixo de tudo.

Então,

```
z-index:0
```

ou

```
  z-index:1
```

Comment: isso é no css ?

Comment: Sim, no css do botão flutuante.

Comment: nem com 0 e nem com 1 não foi amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o position: relative no elemento pai de tudo.
Na tabela tenha uma div que tenha overflow habilitado.
E fora dessa div coloque um botão com position: absolute.

Este [pen](https://codepen.io/arceliver/pen/oorweB) pode te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

```
#voltarAoTopo {
  float:right;
  z-index:0;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:20px;
  right:15px;
}
```

E naquela janela de detalhe, coloca z-index:9;

Você tentou assim?